# Ember.js - Setting for enabling HTTP-only cookies?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, ember.js, httponly

My authentication method sends a HTTP-only cookie to handle sessions. This works fine using [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) and visiting the "login" URL, but as soon as I attempt this on my Ember.js app I get 401 errors when I refresh the app, meaning that cookies aren't saved. Nor do they appear in chrome inspector... Am I missing a parameter that I have to specify?

Answer (score 0):

HttpOnly cookies are *not* meant to be used by javascript.